# Power Up Delay Time of Gate Driver

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

Can someone please explain it to me what does these delay times (highlighted in red box) practically mean during the operation of the gate driver? Attached is the datasheet for the same: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc21222-q1.pdf?ts=1709523651016&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC21222-Q1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation, but that is an isolated driver that uses AC coupled capacitors at the isolation barrier.  These need to be driven with a fast AC signal which is generated by internal oscillators and gated by the input signal.    The oscillator takes time to start up and stabilize.

[image]

Comment: Also speculation, I imagine the output drivers are actively held in a well-defined and non-destructive state, for a short period following application of power, until everything's settled to known conditions.